# Realm Object Server 2.0 install in Azure - returns 404

Tags: realm, azure-virtual-machine

I previously had ROS installed in Azure using the marketplace installation and all worked well. Now that Realm Object Server 2.0 Beta is available I wanted to give it a try so created a new Ubuntu VM in Azure and followed the installation instructions at https://realm.gitbooks.io/realm-object-server/content/installation.html

All seemed to install fine and the server starts up fine with the following output:

```
info: Realm Object Server version 2.0.0-rc.7 is starting
info: Starting auth provider 'password'
info: Realm sync server started ([realm-core-4.0.2], [realm-sync-2.0.2]) service=sync
info: Directory holding persistent state: /home/kwirkykiwi/data/sync/user_data service=sync
info: Operating mode: master_with_no_slave service=sync
info: Listening on 127.0.0.1:43543 (sync protocol version 22) service=sync
info: sync-client: Connection[1]: Connected to endpoint '127.0.0.1:43543' (from '127.0.0.1:51068')
info: sync-client: Connection[2]: Connected to endpoint '127.0.0.1:43543' (from '127.0.0.1:51070')
info: sync-client: Connection[3]: Connected to endpoint '127.0.0.1:43543' (from '127.0.0.1:51072')
info: sync-client: Connection[4]: Connected to endpoint '127.0.0.1:43543' (from '127.0.0.1:51074')
info: 127.0.0.1 - GET /realms/files/%2F__admin HTTP/1.1 200 41 - 20.803 ms
info: 127.0.0.1 - GET /realms/files/%2F__revocation HTTP/1.1 200 46 - 1.869 ms
info: 127.0.0.1 - GET /realms/files/%2F__wildcardpermissions HTTP/1.1 200 55 - 1.172 ms
info: 127.0.0.1 - GET /realms/files/%2F__password HTTP/1.1 200 44 - 0.740 ms
info: Realm Object Server has started and is listening on http://0.0.0.0:9080
info: sync-client: Connection[5]: Connected to endpoint '0.0.0.0:9080' (from '127.0.0.1:60484')
info: sync-client: Connection[6]: Connected to endpoint '0.0.0.0:9080' (from '127.0.0.1:60488')
```

However, when I try to connect to the dashboard by pointing my browser to `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9080` I just get

```
Cannot GET /
```

which I think is a 404 response.

In my SSH window to the server I get the line

```
info: 86.170.194.110 - GET / HTTP/1.1 404 139 - 1.101 ms
```

In the Azure Network Security Group for the VM I have added an Inbound Security Rule to allow destination port 9080 from any source, any protocol.

Is there something else I have to do to open up my server for access from the net? (Sorry, I know next to nothing about servers, networking, or unix!)

Comment: This was answered on the Realm forum https://forums.realm.io/t/ros-2-0-in-azure-installs-and-starts-but-404/587

ROS 2.0 does not have a dashboard anymore - please download our new tool, called Realm Studio: https://realm.io/products/realm-studio/1 - from there you can connect to and administer ROS 2.0.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters "This question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question" - except the "existing" question came into being four days after I posted this one. Did I get stuck in some kind of time warp, or am i missing something? Maybe you should mark the other one as a duplicate instead?

Comment: The answer by Adam Fish was posted there first, then copied here and accepted by you. It did not need copying, Adam should have posted it in one location only. Duplicate posts do not *have* to point from newer to older, they generally need to point to the better question-answer pair.

Answer (score 0):

Realm Object Server does not have a built-in dashboard since 2.0. Realm Studio is supposed to be used instead.